# How to write an helper class with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, google-app-engine, sqlalchemy

I am using google-appengine as my production environment which maintains 12 mysqldb+mysql:// connections with the mysql server,  more than 12 connection it is showing socket open failure.

What i want is, to write a simple crud wrapper.
currently,

```
class CRUDHelper(object):

    _instance = None
    _engine = None
    _session = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        if cls._instance:
            print "Reusing instance"
            return cls._instance
        cls._instance = super(CRUDHelper, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance


    def __init__(self):


        if not CRUDHelper._engine:
            CRUDHelper._engine = create_engine("mysqldb+mysql://test@/test?unix_socket=/cloudsql/appid:appname")
            CRUDHelper._engine.echo = True

        self.engine = CRUDHelper._engine
        if not CRUDHelper._session:
            CRUDHelper._session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autoflush = True, bind=self.engine))

        self.sessionn = CRUDHelper._session
        Base.metadata.create_all(bind= self.engine)


    def get(self, model, id):

        session = self.session()
        # Developer is an sqlalchemy model
        dev = session.query(model).filter_by(id=id).one()
        session.close()
        return dev

    def save(self, object, merge=False):

        self.session.flush()
        if not merge:
            self.session.add(object)
        else:
            self.session.merge(object)
        self.session.commit()
```

this is my crud wrapper. The above code is scalable as well as wont go beyond the 12 connections which is what i desire.

but the problem is.

consider a developer entity with id = 1 has name= "bob" and as age= 23

```
crud = CRUDHelper()
dev = curd.get(Developer, 1)
print dev.age
dev.age += 1
crud.save(dev, merge=True)
```

suppose i run the above snippet of code twice. The expected would be 23 and 24 but i am getting only 23 and 23.

so can any one suggest me what is doing wrong here or give me a snippet of better wrapper with 12 connections cap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer it was a problem with my create_engine function.